# How to execute executable which added to PATH from powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm having problems execute the filename.exe (the name is not relevant) from Windows Powershell. The filename.exe can be executed from the cmd easily, because the file's path is added to the PATH environment variable.
So I can execute the filename.exe like this from command line:

```
filename arg1 arg2
```

I have no idea how to do so in the Powershell.

**Edit:**
I've tried the same way but no success. I got the following message

```
    PS D:\> filename
filename : The term 'filename' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ filename
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (filename:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Should work the same. What error do you get?

Comment: @Aryadev I added more info: check the **Edit**.

Comment: How exactly do you set the environment variable in PowerShell? Keep in mind that normal PowerShell variables are _not_ environment variables (whereas in cmd most of the variables you use _are_ environment variables).

Comment: I haven't set any environment variable in PowerShell. I would like to use path which is in the PATH variable of the Windows. (This might be silly to write down, but just to make clear: I added the "c:\path\to\folder" to the PATH variable. I know that cmd can execute files presented there).

Comment: Was PowerShell running at the time you made that change? Does `$Env:Path` reflect the contents of the variable you expect?

Comment: I made the change like 2 weeks ago :)

Comment: I am not sure if USER env path update would be sufficient but if so, I posted an answer, and you can see it there. I had a blog post explaining how to go about updating System-wide (MACHINE) env. variable as well here: http://www.adilhindistan.com/search?q=powershell+environment+variables

Comment: @Joey You would have the point.The value of my Path variable was too long so it missed the last 4 characters. I had to create another variable and rearrange the value of my Path variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to add an environment variable for that session, in this case update PATH, you can use System.Environment's SetEnvironmentVariable method.

Say, I want to run 7zip, but the path to its executable is not in my path. So if I run it in Powershell, I will get an error:

```
PS > 7z.exe
7z.exe : The term '7z.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ 7z.exe
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (7z.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
PS>
```

Let's add it to the path:

```
PS> [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH',$Env:PATH+';c:\program
files\7-zip')
```

And now run it again:

```
PS > 7z.exe

7-Zip [64] 15.09 beta : Copyright (c) 1999-2015 Igor Pavlov : 2015-10-16
```

Comment: Why to use `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH',$Env:PATH+';c:\program
files\7-zip')` instead of `$Env:PATH+=';c:\program
files\7-zip'`

Comment: Because I am expecting the follow up question to be 'how do I do this system wide'.

Comment: Your answer is partially correct. In the description I mentioned that the variable should have been set. It hasn't worked with your solution either because the path was still too long. It's kinda a mysterious how the cmd version worked just fine.

Comment: The address that you enter should be the location of the .`exe` file, and should not contain the `.exe` file itself. For example, adding `C:\Program Files\Example Program\Example.exe` to your `PATH` does not work, but adding `C:\Program Files\Example Program\ ` does work. I just ran into this issue and took me a few minutes to figure out what was going on. I thought it might help someone else here.